# I want to download a string from an ESP8266 wifi module server using html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html

The ESP is running an Arduino "simple" server! It does not send a "standard" response to a GET request. All it does is send a string that I must parse to get the needed info.

When connecting to the server `http://192.168.4.1` I get back this string:

```
iQUE+2    REPORTS
73
```

Without the standard HTTP headers one would normally expect. As a result most http/js GETs fail because of the lack of standard "status" etc response messages --- at least I think :0) !!

This is the HTML client:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1' />
    <title>iQUE+2 WiFi Monitor</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #cccccc;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
            Color: #000000;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <h1 align=center>Hello from your iQUE<font color=#ff0000>+2
<br>
<br>  </font></h1>
    <h2 align=center>Cooking temperature is: 250</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to get the string from the server and parse out the number then place it where there is currently the number 250 above.

Any ideas/help/sample code/suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I think your out of look, even websockets require a HTTP handshake.  You could do this Server side though using something like node.js.

Comment: The http v0.9 doesn't require the headers at all. The response consists only body should be ok. Try to connect to your server from telnet and send `GET /`<kbd>Enter</kbd>. If you see the expected respinse in the console, then you should be able to do the same from the browser.

Comment: Most modern browsers have/are deprecating or outright dropping support for HTTP 0.9

Comment: Thanks Keith I'll look into node.js

Comment: Thanks djxak  I'm pretty sure you've hit the issue right on the head. The ultimate solution is apparently going to require a server "upgrade" from "simple" :-)

Answer (score 0):

A couple solutions come to mind...

1. You mention this is an ESP8266.  So is it running your own Arduino sketch?  If so, make it speak HTTP 1.x.

If #1 is not an option, then...

2. Throw a second machine into the mix.. one that can speak HTTP 1.x (an IIS or Apache instance, a micro running an HTTP 1.x web server, etc).  This box will proxy incoming requests to the ESP, converting the HTTP 0.9 data into HTTP 1.x data.

Comment: Thanks Sam  No what I was hoping for but good info nevertheless.:-)